Integrating classes in Čech cohomology
In a seminar I attended there was a discussion regarding the first Chern class of line bundles on compact complex manifolds. The exponential sequence $$0 \longrightarrow \mathbb Z \longrightarrow \mathcal O_X \xrightarrow{e^{2\pi i -}} \mathcal O_X^* \longrightarrow 1$$
induces a connecting homomorphism in cohomology,
$$\rho:H^1(X, \mathcal O_X^*) \to H^2(X,\mathbb Z).$$
The question was whether $\rho$ is the first Chern class, or $-\rho$. Clearly, this is the question of normalization of Chern classes. So I thought one could settle this by determining the sign of
$$\int_{\mathbb P^1}\rho(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)).$$
The element $\rho(\mathcal O(1))$ can be rather explicitly calculated using Čech cohomology for an appropriate cover of $\mathbb P^1$, which leads to an integral cocycle
$$(a_{ijk})_{ijk}.$$
At that point I realized that I don't know how to determine $\int_{\mathbb P^1} \alpha$, if $\alpha$ is given as a cocycle in Čech cohomology. Is there an easy way to do this?

Bott and Tu discusses the Cech-de Rham complex which allows you to convert from a Cech cocycle to a differential form using partitions of unity, but I'm not sure how feasible this is to do explicitly

This is answered in my book Introduction to Complex Manifolds, Theorem 7.14. Using the conventions I use there, the first Chern class corresponds to $-\rho$.
(See the remark following the proof of that theorem for a comment about the sign.)

Thank you, that is helpful (even though it doesn't directly answer my question). You write "In some cases, this may just be a matter of choosing a different convention for the transition functions". Do I understand correctly that for different conventions the isomorphism $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X^*) \cong \operatorname{Pic}X$ differs by $(-)^{-1}$?

Not sure what you mean by $(-)^{-1}$. But I suppose it's possible that some authors use an isomorphism between those spaces that differs from mine by a factor of $(-1)$. More likely, some might use a different definition of the connecting homomorphism $\rho$ that differs from mine by a sign.

I think you need the map $(a_{ijk}) \mapsto \sum_{i,j,k} a_{ijk}$. But beware that this depends on many other conventions (e.g., how do you define the differential in the Čech complex).
